# Impossible to install shared library with .so file

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, include, shared-libraries, .so

I'm not able to install [this library](https://github.com/Liris-Pleiad/libcrn) on Ubuntu, or at least to compile a `.cpp` linking the library to it. I have finish all Google and StackOverflow answers.

So ok, first of all I run `cmake` and after I run `make` (and `make install` to be sure). Still, if I run `g++ xxx.cpp -lcrb -o test` I get this error: `fatal error: CRNB.h: No such file or directory`. The library doesn't like to be installed yet, so I copy the `libcrn.so` file  to `/usr/lib` and I run `sudo ldconfig` to load it. Now...

- `sudo ldconfig -n -v /usr/lib/` says it's properly installed (not before copying the `.so` file).
- `g++ -lcrn` says it's properly installed because returns `undefined reference to 'main'` and not `cannot find -lcrn` (as before copying the `.so` file)
- `ldd /bin/ls` doesn't list the library, which means it's not installed

Anyways, trying to compile still throws the same error. I have also tried...

- ... to create a `.conf` file and add it to the folder `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`
- ... to creaty a symbolic link of the `.so` file to `/usr/lib`
- ... to repeat all this solutions also in `/usr/local/lib` and in `/lib` folders
- ... to add all this folders to the `/etc/ld.so.conf` paths
- ... to export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the path of the `.so` file

And many more similar. As you can see all this things are the same, so it's clear that I'm losing something important. Anyone knows what it could be?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `fatal error: CRNB.h: No such file or directory` means it cannot find **header file** `CRNB.h`. Among your attempts, you **never** tried to do something with this file. Actually, after `cmake` - `make` - `make install` the library **is installed**, but it installed *locally*, under `install_3.9.5` subdirectory. So, you may use the library, but need to provide appropriate additional include directories (`-I` flag for `gcc`) and link directories (`-L` flag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify with "-I" flag the include directories, or import it to your system.

Try:

```
g++ src_name.cpp -L./your/library -lcrn -I./your/headers -o out_name -std=c++11
```

Or:

You can copy from libcrn include files ("*.h") to "/usr/local/include/" and the library to "/usr/local/lib/" if doesn't exist, and then:

```
g++ src_name.cpp -lcrn -o out_name -std=c++11
```

Comment: I forgot to copy the include files to /usr/local/include. In this way it works with your last command. Thanks!